# Maxlength not working when using Javascript number inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a slight problem with inserting numbers in the input box.
To be more specific.I use the custom made keypad that shows on the screen,and the numbers can only be written in the input box by using that same keypad,with the max of 5 numbers that can be written.But the HTML `maxlength` atrribute in this case doesn't work.It works when I try to write the number using the actual keyboard,but when inserting with a custom keypad it won't work.

The question is how can I make it to work?

```html
<script>
  function addNumber(element) {

    document.getElementById('child').value = document.getElementById('child').value + element.value;

  }
  function deleteNumber(){
 
 document.getElementById('child').value='';
 
 
}
</script>

<div class='form-group'>
  <div id="staticParent">
    <div class='col-md-6'>
      <input class='form-control' id='child' name="username" type='text' maxlength="5" readonly='readonly' />
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="1" value="1" id="1" onClick=addNumber(this); />
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="2" value="2" id="2" onClick=addNumber(this); />
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="3" value="3" id="3" onClick=addNumber(this); />
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="4" value="4" id="4" onClick=addNumber(this); />
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="5" value="5" id="5" onClick=addNumber(this); />
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="6" value="6" id="6" onClick=addNumber(this); />
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="7" value="7" id="7" onClick=addNumber(this); />
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="8" value="8" id="8" onClick=addNumber(this); />
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="9" value="9" id="9" onClick=addNumber(this); />
      <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="0" value="0" id="0" onClick=addNumber(this); />
      <input type='button' class='fbutton' name='delete' value='Delete' onClick=deleteNumber(this); />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Very bad HTML formatting, and this is not related to jQuery at all.

Comment: Those validation are applied only when user enters the value... not when you make the changes programtically

Comment: Also, not all browsers respect the `maxlength` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace your `addNumber` function with below one, That will solve your problem.

```
 function addNumber(element) {
    var value1 = document.getElementById('child').value + element.value;
    if(value1.length > 5) return false;
    document.getElementById('child').value = value1;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this `maxlength=5`.you will remove `""`

```
<input class='form-control' id='child' name="username" type='text' maxlength=5 readonly='readonly' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `maxlength` only works if the user actually uses the real keyboard and not for programatically changing the value, you can't do it like that.

To get around it simply apply a check in your `addNumber` function:

```
function addNumber() {

  var input = document.getElementById('child');

  if (input.value.length > 5) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

This won't add a new number unless the input length is less or equal to 5.

Also you shouldn't call things with the `onclick` attribute. Instead add your event listeners with `addEventListener`:

```
var addBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('fbutton');

for (var i = 0; i < addBtns.length; i++) {
  addBtns[i].addEventListener('click', addNumber);
}
```

Note that you have to use a loop to add the event listeners since `addBtns` is an array.